# Mongoose populate nested array not working

Tags: javascript, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I'm having an issue populating a nested array of documents with Mongoose and none of the solutions I've seen in other threads seem to work.

Here are the models relevant to my issue:

**Match**

```
const MatchSchema = new Schema({
    home: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Team',
    },
    away: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Team',
    },
    competition: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Competition',
    },
    date: Date,
    live: Boolean,
    odds: [
        {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Odd',
        }
    ],
})
```

**Odd**

```
const OddSchema = new Schema({
    oddValue: Number,
    option: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Option'
    },
    website: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Website'
    },
    market: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Market'
    },
    match: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Match'
    },
})
```

**Market**

```
const MarketSchema = new Schema({
    market: String,
    period: String,

    options: [
        {
            option: {
                type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'Option'
            },
        }
    ],
})
```

**Option**

```
const OptionSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
})
```

Here's how I'm currently populating the documents

```
let matches = await Match.find()
    .populate('home')
    .populate('away')
    .populate({
        path: 'competition',
        populate: [
            { path: 'country', model: 'Country' },
            { path: 'sport', model: 'Sport'}
        ]
    })
    .populate({
        path: 'odds',
        populate: [
            { path: 'option', model: 'Option' },
            { path: 'website', model: 'Website' },
            { path: 'market', model: 'Market' }
        ]
    })
```

I'm having issues populating the nested 'options' field in the populated market document.

I've tried chaining populate calls, like

```
.populate({
        path: 'odds',
        populate: {
            { path: 'market', model: 'Market', 
              populate: { path:'options.option', model: 'Option' }}
        }
    })
```

but I keep getting the same output of the Odd documents, where all fields are successfully populated except the options array in the nested market field.

[odd output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihNSP.png)

Is there something wrong with the way I'm organising data? Am I calling populate incorrectly?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The options field in the Market model was not defined correctly. Should be

```
const MarketSchema = new Schema({
    market: String,
    period: String,

    options: [
        {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Option'
        }
    ],
})
```